# Switching 3rd party compilers in devenv from the command line

Tags: visual-studio-2005, compiler-construction, intel

We have an automated build system, which builds a variety of Visual Studio 2005 solution files. These solutions contain various Visual C++ and Intel Fortran projects.

We are in the process of upgrading our Intel Fortran compiler, and Visual Studio is currently setup to be integrated with the old Intel compiler (ver 9.1).

I'm looking for a way to tell Visual Studio to use the new Intel Fortran compiler (ver 11). I need to be able to tell Studio to do this just for our compiler upgrade project, with it's default remaining as is (using ver 9.1) so that our standard builds can continue without being affected by the upgrade project.

Does anybody know if this is possible? I.e., can I tell Visual Studio which Intel compiler to use via the command line?

At the moment, I can use the batch scripts that Intel supply to setup the LIB=, INCLUDE= and PATH= environment variables. However, when Visual Studio compiles the Fortran projects, it's using ver 9.1.

Answer (score 2):

What about the "/useenv" command line to devenv.exe?

```
C:\>devenv /?

Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 8.0.50727.867.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.

Use:
devenv  [solutionfile | projectfile | anyfile.ext]  [switches]
...
/useenv         Use PATH, INCLUDE, LIBPATH, and LIB environment variables
                instead of IDE paths for VC++ builds.
```